# Using epls for multiple dependent level calculations

Tags: java, esper, calculation, epl

I am new to **Esper**. I need help to maintain the **EPL** flow. I have a *java* class *EsperTest.java*, that class is sending the data to **EPL** for the calculation in every 10 Sec.

In **EPL's** I have 4 *Compression* Level. E.g. *CompressionA, CompressionB, CompressionC, CompressionD.* In each compression, we are performing grouping based on some fields.

After the calculation has been completed for *CompressionA*, we raised an Event i.e '**CompressionACompleted**'. On the basis of '**CompressionACompleted**', we start calculation of *CompressionB*. And after the calculation has been completed for *CompressionB*, we raised an Event i.e '**CompressionBCompleted**'. On the basis of '**CompressionBCompleted**', we start calculation of *CompressionC* and so on.

Now the problem is that I have a list that contains 100 values. The java class (*EsperTest.java*) is sending the value to Esper one by one. And so all compressions are calculated for each value in the list.

Now, I want that 1 compression should calculate one for all 100 changes. i.e. when 100 values are sent to **EPL** then *CompressionA* should calculate for all 100 value 1 time, then CompressionB should start updating once *CompressionA* is complete and update for the whole window. Then CompressionC should start updating once B completes calculation.

Our current flow is causing high **CPU usage** or High memory consumption as if changed value number increases calculation time and complexity increases. Please help me to change **EPL's** structure in my application.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked an answered on the Esper mailing list.